# How to Change File Extension, Windows/Windows Explorer

Tags: android, windows, explorer

Recently I installed a program which changed all my `.apk` files into `.°²×¿Èí¼þ×°ÎÄ¼þ (.apk) (.apk)` files.

**NOTE:** It's only changed the displaying extension of the files, in Windows Explorer. The actual file extension (as discovered via cmd) is still .apk

I tried renaming the file, but that doesn't let me change the file extension.

Is there any way I can change these back into `.apk` files?

I was wondering if you might be able to with the registry editor, or via some sneaky underhand methods.

Please help.

Comment: Did you enable 'view file extensions' in 'folder options'?

Comment: What program you have installed? Is it virus or normal program? You could use any Linux LiveCD to change the name, but it is, may be, some harder way than you need.

Comment: @Mramaa Yes, I'm not an idiot ;)

Comment: Haha ok just to be sure

Comment: @JohnSmith It's ishuaji , for rooting android devices.It's not a virus, it's just Chinese that my computer can't display properly.

Comment: @minseong what happens when you try to rename it?

Comment: @JohnSmith Right Click -> Rename: Lets me rename the file name, doesn't display the extension in the renaming-area-thingy.

Comment: @minseong hmm.. it is strange. Can you change extension of file by cmd.exe?

Comment: @JohnSmith It's not the extension that's changed, cmd still recognises them by .apk, it's just the way explorer displays it.

Comment: Could you show your HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.app regisry key? (You can create reg file with RegEdit)

Comment: @DenisAnisimov I have no .app key, I do have a HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.application though, but it contains nothing useful.

Comment: Sorry, I mean HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.apk

Comment: @DenisAnisimov That doesn't exist, but don't worry - I just uninstalled the program, so it might have existed before, everything's sane now (no more zalgo file extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**maybe** if you deactivate new application to open .apk files your problem resolved. 
go to regedit (type regedit in RUN and press OK). from file menu, export the registry to restore if it will be need next. 
go to this address in registry:

```
“HKEY_CURRENT_USER \Software \Microsoft \Windows \CurrentVersion \ Explorer \FileExts\”
```

there is a list of extensions, find .apk and click on it, you can see a list of programs in right panel to open .apk files. 
then delete new program that's your opinion from list.

Comment: What a great answer! I'd already deleted and uninstalled the program, but this would have definitely helped me! You've certainly opened up my eyes to a feature I had no idea existed!

Answer (score 0):

Windows huh? If you've not disabled System Restore and these files were on your system drive, you may be able to mount the shadow volume.

"Volume Shadow Copy maintains snapshots of entire volumes. By default, it is turned on for your system volume (C:) and protects all the data on that volume, including all the system files, program files, user settings, documents, etc".